# How to determine the amount of memory used by unmanaged code

Tags: com, unmanaged, arcobjects

I'm working against a large COM library (ArcObjects) and I'm trying to pinpont a memory leak.
What is the most reliable way to determine the amount of memory used by unmanaged code/objects.
What performance counters can be used?

Answer (score 2):

Use [UMDH](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268343) to get snapshot of your memory heap, run it twice then use the tools to show all the allocations that occurred between the 2 snapshots. This is great in helping you track down which areas might be leaking.

[This article](http://weblogs.asp.net/mdavey/archive/2004/03/09/86569.aspx) explains in in simple terms.

I suggest you use a CComPtr<> to wrap your objects, not forgetting that you must release it before passing it into a function that returns a raw pointer reference (as the cast operator will be used to get the pointer that then gets overwritten)

Answer (score 0):

The 'Virtual Bytes' counter for a process represents the total amount of memory the process has reserved.  If you have a memory leak then this will trend upwards.